# Create Charts in .net Core and save as image

Tags: c#, .net-core, drawing, pie-chart, image-manipulation

So I am trying to create a Pie Chart in c# (.net Core). The only problem is that there are no packages available/working on .net Core. I even tried to do it myself with ImageSharp and Magick.Net but couldn't figure out how to draw a slice of a circle.

Anyway it should be available for commercial use and .net Core. Also a package to draw slices of a circle on an image would be enough for me.

What I tried with Magick.NET:

```css
using (var baseimage = new MagickImage("Images/Background.png"))
{

baseimage.Draw(new Drawables().Ellipse(600,600,100,100,0,80).FillColor(MagickColors.Red));

var stream = new MemoryStream();
baseimage.Write(stream);
stream.Position = 0;
...

}
```

That was the closest I got to: [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbG5e.png)
The red part was created by the program and the yellow outlined should be filled aswell.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: `The only problem is that there are no packages available/working on .net Core` rubbish... `I even tried to do it myself with ImageSharp and Magick.Net but couldn't figure out how to draw a slice of a circle` what did you try and why isnt working,

Comment: @TheGeneral I hope this helps.

Comment: Did you see[this](https://developers.de/2018/01/22/how-to-use-system-drawing-in-net-core/) ?

Comment: Oh thank you alot!

Comment: It should be noted that System.Drawing.Common (used in above sent link) is now deprecated for non-Windows OSs.